# Cordova check if file in url exists

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build

I am using cordova / phonegap and need to know if a file exists

Here's the code with the path and filename:

```
storeUrl = cordova.file.dataDirectory+'myfolder/myfile.mp3';
```

How can I check if this file exists?

Comment: What this program properly doing, @Satch3000?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try code from this link:
https://cordovablogsblogs.wordpress.com/2015/06/10/how-to-check-a-files-existence-in-phone-directory-with-phonegap/.
Code:

```
function checkIfFileExists(path){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){
        fileSystem.root.getFile(path, { create: false }, fileExists, fileDoesNotExist);
    }, getFSFail); //of requestFileSystem
}
function fileExists(fileEntry){
    alert("File " + fileEntry.fullPath + " exists!");
}
function fileDoesNotExist(){
    alert("file does not exist");
}
function getFSFail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}
```

Comment: tried checkIfFileExists(theurl + fileName);  but that returns that the file does not exist when it does

Comment: Check value of cordova.file.dataDirectory using instruction alert(cordova.file.dataDirectory);.

Comment: Thank you! What an awesome little set of functions to solve this problem. +lots

Answer (score 8):

**Update**:
Works on iOS too.

**Try:**

```
function checkIfFileExists(path){
    // path is the full absolute path to the file.
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, fileExists, fileDoesNotExist);
}
function fileExists(fileEntry){
    alert("File " + fileEntry.fullPath + " exists!");
}
function fileDoesNotExist(){
    alert("file does not exist");
}
```

Found the solution [here](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/07/01/Cordova-Sample-Check-for-a-file-and-download-if-it-isnt-there/).

Works on Android. Will test on iOS and update this answer.