# Download file for offline use Cordova/PhoneGap build

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

I'm a novice when it comes to the development of apps. I made a simple audio player app for android and iOS and build it with phonegap build.

The app uses the `<audio>` html tag to load mp3 files that are located on a remote server like so:

```
            <div class="mobileui-music-cover-controls">
    <audio ontimeupdate="udpateProgress()" id="player">
        <source src="http://www.myserver.com/audiofile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">          
    </audio>
            <a id="playKnop" href="JavaScript:playMusic()" class="play"><i class="ion-ios-play"></i></a>
            <a id="pauseKnop" href="JavaScript:pauseMusic()" class="play"><i class="ion-ios-pause"></i></a>
        </div>
```

obviously, I changed the `scr` for this example.

It works fine as long as you have a stable internet connection but a few people are experiencing connection drops etc.
I would like to make the files offline available on user request. So it has to be optional (by clicking a button or something like that). 
The app should detect if the file is present on the device and if so choose the local file over the remote file.

In short, I have 2 questions.

1. How can I download a specific file on user request?
2. How can I check whether the file is there or not and play the right file?

I can't seem to figure out how to do this I'm working on it for the last couple of days but I honestly have no clue on how to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As you said you need to download the file to your device. Since your using cordova you could use [fileTransfer](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) to download the audio. This is very straight forward (this is the offical example code):

```
// !! Assumes variable fileURL contains a valid URL to a path on the device,
//    for example, cdvfile://localhost/persistent/path/to/downloads/

var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("http://some.server.com/download.php");

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    fileURL,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("download error code" + error.code);
    },
    false,
    {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
        }
    }
);
```

The next time you want to play the audio you need to check if there is a local version. Either you check your device if that file exists (there are many ways, e.g. [Cordova check if file in url exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34692092/cordova-check-if-file-in-url-exists)) or you make use of something like [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp) which basically is a simple lil database.

```
// more or less pseudo code!!!

// callback from fileTransfer when your file was downloaded
function downloadSuccess(entry) {
    // save it to localStorage 
    // key: the remote URL, value: the local URL
    localStorage.setItem(remoteURL, entry.toURL());
}

...
...

// the check if there is a cached file
var remoteSrc = "http://www.myserver.com/audiofile.mp3";
var localSrc = localStorage.getItem(remoteSrc);

if(localSrc === null) {
    // when there is NO cached version, use remote
    audioElement.src = remoteSrc;
} else {
    // when there IS a cached version, use local
    audioElement.src = localSrc;
}
```

I hope this helps and gives you an idea how to accomplish simple caching yourself :)